# I Don't Need a Facebook App, I just want their API (in Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, facebook, facebooker

Can I use Facebooker without having to [create a whole Facebook App](http://developers.facebook.com/) in their Developer section?

I don't need to create a [Facebook App with Facebooker](http://apps.facebook.com/facebooker_tutorial/), I just want to be able to create events and posts on Facebook with my own custom admin panel on my site.  Facebooker seems to have everything built already, so I wouldn't want to use just a raw Rest-Client library.

Can I use Facebooker to read/write to Facebook without creating an App?  I'd love to know.  If not, can I read/write to Facebook without creating an App another way without resorting to either raw REST requests or page scraping/mechanize?

Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have created an App in order to get an API key and Secret Key. You must have these keys in order to use any of the FB platform API (including Facebook connect).